# How to return column changes in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a list on dates, and all I want to do is return the changes from row to row.

For example:

```
id   date
1     2022-08-30
2     2022-08-31
3     2022-09-01
4     2022-09-02
5     2022-09-02
6     2022-09-05
```

and I would like to return something like "The date changed from 2022-08-30 to 2022-08-31"
and "The date changed from 2022-08-31 to 2022-09-01" and so on.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `LEAD` and/or `LAG`?

Comment: I wasn't aware of LEAD, but this looks like exactly what I'm looking for. thank you so much.